# LibreOffice sort function is very slow

Tags: libreoffice

I am using LO 4.2.8.2 on Ubuntu 14.04. I have 4G of RAM, 23% of them are used for background processes. When I try to sort a calc sheet by selecting the whole sheet, I get very slow response, more that 30 sec to sort 3 columns and 35 rows.  Selecting only the 3 columns works fast. I do not recall such behavior in the past. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

LibreOffice has the `memory option` that controls how much system memory and in what manner will it be used in operating LibreOffice.

Since the default memory limits the usage, LibreOffice does not utilize the system memory at fullest, even if it is available.

To access the memory option, go to the top menu and then go to `tools`-----`options`.

In here, choose the Memory option from left hand side. You will see several options in the right panel for increasing memory allocations.

When you have applied these changes successfully, you will feel that LibreOffice opens quickly and runs faster.

Comment: I cannot downvote, but this is just an annoying answer. I've played with the memory option and it makes no difference on some of the things that are really important: sorting and vlookups.

Comment: @Crhis Matenaers: I regret that the proposed solution has not worked for you. I participate only trying to help, within my means and not to vote me positive.